# Seeking advice on having a more feminine body as a male (Without hormones)

Tags: workout-routines, diet

Good day;

I would like to ask what sort of diet and exercise you'd recommend for me to achieve having a more feminine figure being a man?

I'm around 280Lbs so far so I know my first step will be to lose half of that (i'm 5'5).

I've been researching how I could first lose this weight efficiently through certain workout and diet, however even going to the gym 3 times a week with 30 minutes of cardio each time, I cannot seem to make any results appear after 2 months, which is really killing my motivation...

Thanks in advance for your advices.

Edit for JohnP #1 : I walk about 4000 steps in average per day, and add about 30 minutes of cycling 4 times a week; my daily calorie intake is about 1500.

Comment: What do you mean by “feminine body”? Do you have standard man boobs or something like gynecomastia? At 5’5” and 280 lbs I couldn’t imagine your body looking particularly masculine or feminine in general otherwise. There’s simply too much fat covering your figure at that point to make a call like that.

Comment: @JustSnilloc - I *think* the poster would like to lose weight, and end up with a feminine as opposed to masculine build. I'm not really sure what that means, so until the original poster can clarify what they want for goals and provide other information, I'll be placing this on hold.

Comment: We don't have enough information to be able to help here. We have no idea how many calories you are eating in a day, what you consider "30 minutes of cardio", etc. Please add more detail to be able to reopen your post. I will say that the vast majority of weight loss lies in your approach to eating, not in simply adding cardio.

Comment: @JohnP; Sorry, i thought I was being clear enough, but I'm not good at fitness yet and what people might need to know.

Comment: @Musuyajin - No worries. I don't think that's really enough detail to get really good answers, but I'll reopen it. Thank you for the edits.

Comment: By 1,5k do you mean 1500 calories? Or 15000? If it is 1500, then I think you are vastly underestimating your intake. I am slightly taller and 100 lbs less, and 1500 doesn't even reach my basal needs. At your height/weight, your basic needs would be ~2200 calories just to sit and breathe all day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once your bones have been shaped you can't do much.

A male figure is recognizable from every angle, and losing weight is the worst you can do if you want a feminine body.

I actually have a friend who cross dresses and he built so much leg musculature with the right portion of body fat that from the abs down looks like a female, he's 24.

Also posture is really important, the back bend of a female is really different from the male one.

I would aim to build a strong gluteus and quadricep musculature and reaching at least 17% bodyfat, slightly higher might be safer.

Your worst problem will be thoracic posture, men maturally tend to breathe with their chest and stand up tall shoulder straight, avoid that.